# for loop does not passes through next element

Tags: r

The below code executes successfully but it stops if it finds `stats` dataframe has got 0 rows and its not executing and rbind the next set of rows that have more than 0 rows, so as to encounter that I have put a `next` statement still it stops. Please help me out!

```
textrank<-NULL
for(i in lista){
  if(i %in% dflist_T$VariaF){
    Eachdesc <- subset(dflist_T, VariaF %in% i)
    ud_model <- udpipe_load_model(model$file_model)
    x <- udpipe_annotate(ud_model,x = Eachdesc$Description)

    x <- as.data.frame(x)
    stats <- keywords_rake(x = x, 
                           term = "token", group = c("doc_id", "paragraph_id", "sentence_id"),
                           relevant = x$upos %in% c("NOUN", "ADJ"),
                           ngram_max = 4)
    stats$Origin <- "dflist"
    stats$lista <- i
    if (nrow(stats) == 0) {
      next}
    textrank<-rbind(textrank,stats)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just rbind dependently.

edit: you should also check whether `textrank` already exists. So I included an `is.null()` check

```
textrank <- NULL
for(i in lista){
  if(i %in% dflist_T$VariaF){
    Eachdesc <- subset(dflist_T, VariaF %in% i)
    ud_model <- udpipe_load_model(model$file_model)
    x <- udpipe_annotate(ud_model,x = Eachdesc$Description)

    x <- as.data.frame(x)
    stats <- keywords_rake(x = x, 
                           term = "token", group = c("doc_id", "paragraph_id", "sentence_id"),
                           relevant = x$upos %in% c("NOUN", "ADJ"),
                           ngram_max = 4)
    stats$Origin <- "dflist"
    stats$lista <- i

    # check for non empty stats and existent textrank
    if(nrow(stats) != 0 & !is.null(textrank)) {
      textrank <- rbind(textrank, stats)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: still i get error saying ```Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Origin", value = "dflist") : 
  replacement has 1 row, data has 0```

Comment: Then please provide a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/8107362). Especially, provide some sample data, e.g. with `dput()`.